# Azure tools for Visual Studio - How to use with existing cloud service?

Tags: azure

How do I use the Azure Tools for Visual Studio to maintain an existing cloud service such as a mobile service?  Say I have one deployed to Azure already with a database attached, push notification, scripts etc.  Is it possible to connect to this using Visual Studio, download the code, make changes and then publish again?

I don't see anywhere in Visual Studio where we can connect and view existing code that resides in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anyway to automatically download the code afaiki, but you can connect in Server Explorer in VS.  Once you have the project in VS you can publish changes back to the service just as you do with a regular web app using the publish wizard.